# Which itertools generator doesn't skip any combinations?

Tags: python, python-itertools

When I run this code I don't get all the possible combinations of 3 characters:

```
def comb(iterable, r):
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    for indices in permutations(range(n), r):
        if sorted(indices) == list(indices):
            yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
def start():
    for x in comb("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ12234567890!@#$%^&*?,()-=+[]/;",3):
        print x
```

Instead it skips some. When I repeated the characters 3 times, I got all the combinations I needed, but I get some multiple times. This takes triple the time and isn't what I want. I'm going to be calculating millions of of combinations so I need to to know an alternative to repeating the characters.

Comment: Lets say you wanted length 2 instead of instead of 3, and you had `abcd` as your string. What would you want the output to be? `ab, ac, ad, bc, bd, cd`? `aa, ab, ac, ad, bb, bc, bd, cc, cd, dd`? `aa, ab, ac, ad, ba, bb, bc, bd, ca, cb, cc, cd, da, db, dc, dd`? `ab, ac, ad, ba, bc, bd, ca, cb, cd, da, db, dc`? Something else?

Comment: aa, ab, ac, ad, ba, bb, bc, bd, ca, cb, cc, cd, da, db, dc, dd is the output I'm looking for.

Comment: In case you do not find a way to do w/o the long string literal, you may want to look at what you can import from `string`. E.g.,

     `from string import printable`
     `print printable`

yields
    
     `0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~`

without error (in your example 2 is listed twice, and other characters might be missing)

Smaller specific subsets are available too, like `ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase, punctuation` and `digits`

Comment: People would be having a hard time understanding the question. This requires rewording.

Comment: @Abhijit all the info we needed was in his comment :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for `itertools.product(characters, repeat = 3)`.

See the [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) docs.

```
>>> ' '.join(''.join(x) for x in itertools.product('abcd', repeat = 2))
aa ab ac ad ba bb bc bd ca cb cc cd da db dc dd
```

Comment: This is almost what I want. However, when I did a test at a repeat of 2 when it hit "('b', 'c')" I want it to be "('b', 'a')" It totally skipped over the 'a'. This also happens for the rest except skipping the corresponding letter before it.

Comment: @NoahR You made a mistake. Look at the example in my answer. It hits every set of two, including doubled letters, with order mattering -- `ba` and `ab` are considered different. I've use `product` many times to do exactly what you're doing. What you're describing is `combinations_with_replacement`, not `product`.

Comment: Could you use my code edit it and post it on your answer so I can see clearly what you're doing that I'm not?

Comment: @NoahR You don't need any of your code at all, except the `for` loop. Just `for chars in itertools.product(characters, repeat = 3): print chars` would do it. You don't need `combs`, which is a really inefficient way of generating combinations from permutations and was meant only as an example in the docs. It has nothing to do with `product`.

Comment: You're really looking for permutations, or combinations with replacement.  See Lossy's answer.

Comment: @Brendan No, he's not. Look at his comment on the question. He wants `aa`, `ba` and `ab` -- only `product` will give him all 3. `permutations` won't give him `aa`, `combinations` won't give him eiher `aa` or `ba`, and `combinations_with_replacement` won't give him `ba`. I asked him a very carefully constructed question in the comments in order to determine which one he wanted.

Comment: For what it's worth (not much more than moral support I'm afraid), I agree that this is 100% correct according to Noah R's comments. As a side note, I find that the word "combination" is _horribly_ abused in all sorts of ways. "On this site" I was about to say -- but really -- everywhere. Sigh.

Comment: @senderle It's always a problem when words have both formal meanings in a jargon and informal meanings. I've accidentally insulted people by calling something "trivial" when I meant "simple", which is what it means in mathematics, but they assumed I meant "unimportant". It's good to have someone back me up here so future readers don't get even more confused.

Comment: @senderle It appears the disagreeing user has been deleted, leaving only his posts behind.