# How to use itertools product with a huge data

Tags: python, list, product, python-itertools

I would like to make a list of 81-tuple by using three elements, namely 1,2,3 in python.

I tried to find a solution, and then I found these useful links:

[How to use itertools to compute all combinations with repeating elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23833780/how-to-use-itertools-to-compute-all-combinations-with-repeating-elements)

and

[Which itertools generator doesn't skip any combinations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234599/which-itertools-generator-doesnt-skip-any-combinations)

According to the above links, I should do the following

```
import itertools

list = []
for p in itertools.product(range(1, 3 + 1), repeat=81):
    list.append(p)

print(list)
```

But, my computer hangs. I think there is too much data in the list.

I want to know whether there is a command that prints only first 100-elements in list or the 101th to 200th in the list.

Comment: You are trying to create a list of 443426488243037769948249630619149892803 items. Possibly you are running out of RAM :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
p = itertools.product(range(1, 3 + 1), repeat=81)
s = itertools.islice(p, 101, 200)
print(list(s))
```

This will, however, iterate through all the elements until it reaches the starting index of the slice. So for ranges towards the end of an iterator with a gazillion elements (yours has `3**81 = 443426488243037769948249630619149892803` or in other words: too many to process let alone store), this will run into similar problems.

For those later ranges, you would have to calculate the n-th element by hand and generate successors from there... See [How to select specific item from cartesian product without calculating every other item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944915/how-to-select-specific-item-from-cartesian-product-without-calculating-every-oth)  for some inspiration.

Comment: After I use this, it shown <itertools.product object at 0x0000024391C65EE8>.

Comment: Yeah, that's the point of a lazy iterator: you have to iterate it (partially) or convert it to a list to see the elements. Hence, you slice it first (which involves some iterations), then convert it to a list, then print it (as in the code example).

Comment: @schowobaseggl can you take a look at my issue here You have previously provided guidance to a similar question (this post), but I couldn't figure out how to implement it on my script: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65743187/